# WP Customizer set a value via javascript (to create presets)

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I am trying to find a way to send a value between 2 setting fields inside of the WordPress customizer.

My further goal is to create a preset button. I click a button inside of the customizer, and it applies pre-created values to all the other fields.

To make it easier, here is a basic example:

I have two option fields inside of the customizer. When I change the value of `field 1`, I would like `field 2` to automatically updates to that same value as well.

`theme-customizer.js`

```
// Field 1
    wp.customize( 'field1', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
                //no need to make any css changes with this field.
        } );
    } );    

// Field 2
    wp.customize( 'field2', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
            $('.site-container').css('border-style', newval +'px' );
        } );
    } );
```

Is there away that I could update the value of `field2` when `field1` is clicked?

For example:

```
// Field 1
    wp.customize( 'field1', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
                wp.customize.value( 'field2 )(newval);//Setting the new value.
        } );
    } );
```

This does work on the live preview, but the new value of `field2` is not being saved when I click save. It seems the value is not being put through to PHP when using:

```
wp.customize.value( 'field2 )(newval);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to simply enqueue the JS value syncing snippet so that it is added in the customizer pane (`customize.php`) instead of the customizer preview window (on the frontend). In other words, enqueue your JS at `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Here's one snippet:

```
wp.customize( 'field1', 'field2', function( field1, field2 ) {
    field1.bind( function( value ) {
        field2.set( value );
    } );
} );
```

And here's an even more succinct example that does the same thing:

```
wp.customize( 'field1', 'field2', function( field1, field2 ) {
    field2.link( field1 );
} );
```

Nevertheless, if you have the same value stored in multiple settings, why not just re-use the same setting in multiple places?